# Totient summatory function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, totient-function, conjectures

Let $\Phi(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)$ be the totient summatory function.
Here is an interesting conjecture I've made: The ratio $\Phi(n^2)/\Phi(n)$ is an integer only for $n=1,2,3,5$ and $6$. I made a program that shows that these are only solution for about $n<3000$. Is there some way to prove or disaprove it?

Eventually, what about the general case: what conditions should satisfy numbers $n$ and $m$ so that ratio of their totient summatory functions is integer? Is there some paper that deals with it?

Comment: The "probability" that a randomly chosen integer is divisible by $\Phi(n)$ is $1/\Phi(n)$, which is roughly a constant times $1/n^2$. So the expected number of $n$ for which $\Phi(n)$ divides $a_n$, for any randomly chosen sequence $a_n$ in place of $\Phi(n^2)$, is finite. Thus it's not surprising that this particular case would have only finitely many solutions. Proving this is, of course, another matter....

Comment: I realise that if this conjecture is true it is not surprising but I would like to know are there any ideas how to try to prove it (if it is true). Most things I read about totient summatory function are dealing with it's boundness so I don't know are there any good papers that deal with ratios functions.

Comment: I suspect a proof is hopeless. $\Phi(n^2)$ is an additive (and unmotivated) function that it seems really unlikely to get any multiplicative information about it. (Of course I've been wrong before.)

Comment: I mostly agree with you, but that fact that solutions are only small possitive integers leaves some hope that proof is possible.

Answer (score 1):

A proof of this conjecture will be out of reach with high probability. Apparently, no useful formula for the sum of the first $k$ totients is known. According to the following PARI/GP - program, there is no further solution upto $n=31\ 000$ :

```
? t=1;s=1;n=1;while(s<10^9,s=s+1;if(Mod(s,10^7)==0,print1(s/10^7,"  "));n=n+eule
rphi(s);if(issquare(s)==1,t=t+eulerphi(sqrtint(s));if(Mod(n,t)==0,print;print(sq
rtint(s));print)))

2


3


5


6

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  2
3  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  4
3  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  6
3  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  8
3  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100
?
```

Perhaps, someone tries this program with a higher limit. At the point $n^2\approx 10^9$, the denominator in your ratio is already approximately $3\cdot 10^8$, so if a further solution exists, it will probably be quite large, perhaps too large for brute-force calculation.

Comment: Does the downvoter have any better idea than brute force ?